# Array_search query in array

Tags: php, arrays

I could not get array key .

For example : i created array with information

`[0] => Andrey:Makarov:525359:east::57.9318:33.2573:31591:424:1 [1] => John:Smith:752351:east::56.7318:23.6373:37491:424:1` and etc.

How i can find key of array if i know only identifier of person - 525359 ? 
i have tried this code

`$key = array_search('525359',$array);
echo 'key is',$key;`

but it not works .

Maybe i need try create pattern attribute like in HTML ?

Comment: Fix your data structure into something useable.

Comment: It will take much time , and in one file i have  about 1000 records ,but i need get only 3-4 records in mysql database .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example to get key based on regular expression , like it return the key of element who matches with ee inside a value .

```
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

$key=0;
foreach ($colors as $value) {
    if (preg_match("*ee*", $value)) {
                       echo $value." has key = ".$key."<br>";
               break;
      } else {
          $key++;
      }

}
```

output of this code is

green has key = 1

Answer (score 0):

array_search only returns array entries with exact matches in the values.

The best option would be to re-key your array based on the identifier you wanted to match against, allowing you to filter more easily.

The second best option might be to use `preg_grep` which can search for a regular expression through the array entries. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Comment: thanks, but if i want get all string of array where there is this identifier , i think `preg_grep` will not help .

Comment: preg_grep will return the entries matching the given pattern. If the pattern is `/^[^:]*:[^:]*:525359:/` it will give you the desired entries

Comment: You can then use a preg_quote'd variable in place of 525359 to search for different entries. As mentioned the best option is to simply re-key the array.

Comment: Thanks , now i fixed this problem by code of Pintu Lal M .